# Of what material were the staffs made in Parshas Korach?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parshat-korach

[Bamidbor 17 (17)](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.17.17?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en) records the instruction to take a staff for each of the chieftains.

> דַּבֵּ֣ר ׀ אֶל־בְּנֵ֣י יִשְׂרָאֵ֗ל וְקַ֣ח מֵֽאִתָּ֡ם מַטֶּ֣ה מַטֶּה֩
>   לְבֵ֨ית אָ֜ב מֵאֵ֤ת כָּל־נְשִֽׂיאֵהֶם֙ לְבֵ֣ית אֲבֹתָ֔ם שְׁנֵ֥ים
>   עָשָׂ֖ר מַטּ֑וֹת אִ֣ישׁ  אֶת־שְׁמ֔וֹ תִּכְתֹּ֖ב עַל־מַטֵּֽהוּ׃
>
> Speak to the Israelite people and take from them—from the chieftains
>   of their ancestral houses—one staff for each chieftain of an ancestral
>   house: twelve staffs in all. Inscribe each man’s name on his staff,

One might have thought that in order to have a fair test, these staffs should have been made from the same material.

Of what material(s) were the staffs made?

Note: Jewish Encyclopedia contains the following - Midrash Yelamdenu (Yalḳ. on Ps. ex. § 869)

> "It was made of sapphire, weighed forty seahs (a seah = 10.70 pounds)…

but I do not know how authoritative this is.

Related: [The blossoming of Ahron's staff a miracle not a trick?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/73534/the-blossoming-of-ahrons-staff-a-miracle-not-a-trick)

Comment: Considering that Aharon's staff bore almonds, what would make you think that all the other ones would not have been made from almond bark?

Comment: Notice, besides Kicha it does not say "make the staffs" so I would suppose they were ready-made, i.g. regular sticks.

Comment: Re: Jewish Encyclopedia: That have an unsourced claim that Aaron's Rod was Moshe's famous Rod. Hard to believe they shared a rod.

Answer (score 1):

[The Tzror Hamor](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45935&st=&pgnum=243) says all the staffs were made out of one piece of almond wood.

[image]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken *The Midrash Says* says this as well, likely from this source or another similar one.